# Hiding dynamically generated content by default

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my javascript file, I have the following template string that contains a `form` with `id="update-quote-form"` that I'd like to hide by default:

```
$("#quoteTarget").append(
          `<h3>${index.phrase}</h3>
              <h4>${index.author}</h4>
            <div class="childshow">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="delete-quote">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" value="${index._id}">
                </a>

                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="update-quote">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" value="${index._id}">
                </a>

                <div class='childshow'>
                  <form id="update-quote-form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="text" name="phrase" class="form-control" placeholder="${index.phrase}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="text" name="author" class="form-control" placeholder="${index.author}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input class="temp" type="submit" value="submit change" name="${index._id}">
                    </div>
                  </form>
                </div>
            </div>
              <hr>`
```

I'd like to have it hidden before using toggle to have it appear. This is the click handler im using to toggle this id:

```
$('#quoteTarget').hover(function() {
  $(".childshow").on("click",function (e) {
      console.log("hi");
      e.stopPropagation();
      $(this).children('.childshow').toggle();
  });
```

I tried having it set to `display: none` in the css, but I believe the click handler won't notice it since it hasn't loaded.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Add your HTML code as well to the question. Where is the `quoteTarget` element and the form `update-quote-form`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setting css `display` should work fine (I've modified the code a bit though) -

```js
var index={author:"test", phrase:"test phrase",_id:1}
$("#quoteTarget").append(
  `<h3>${index.phrase}</h3>
              <h4>${index.author}</h4>
            <div class="childshow">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="delete-quote">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" value="${index._id}">
                </a>

                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="update-quote">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" value="${index._id}">
                </a>

                <div class='childshow'>
                <div class="childshow-header">Click me</div>
                <div class="childshow-content">
                  <form id="update-quote-form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="text" name="phrase" class="form-control" placeholder="${index.phrase}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="text" name="author" class="form-control" placeholder="${index.author}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input class="temp" type="submit" value="submit change" name="${index._id}">
                    </div>
                  </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
              <hr>`);

//$('#quoteTarget').hover(function() {
  $(".childshow-header").on("click", function(e) {
    //console.log("hi");
   // e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).next(".childshow-content").toggle();
  });
//});
```

```css
.childshow-header{
  width:100%;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: gray;
}

.childshow-content{
  display:none;
}
.
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="quoteTarget">

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. However for some reason adding the click target class "childshow-header" to my glyphicon isnt working. Tried replacing with a button as well and it still doesnt toggle. Not sure why this is happening.

Comment: @DanT - if you could create a plunker for this, I can help.